# Encoding string in UTF8 from list

Tags: python, excel, utf-8, xlrd

I'm having trouble formating the strings to utf-8
In this script im getting data from excel file
then printing it out in a loop, the problem is that
the string with special characters shows up wrong.

In result I keep getting 'PatrÄ«cija' instead of 'Patrīcija'
Can't seem to find the solution for this problem

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import sys
    import xlrd
    import datetime

    def todaysnames():
    todaysdate = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.date.today(), "%d.%m")

    book = xlrd.open_workbook("vardadienas.xls")
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Calendar')
    for rownr in range(sheet.nrows):
        if sheet.cell(rownr, 0).value == todaysdate:
            string = (sheet.cell(rownr, 1).value)
            string = string.encode(encoding="UTF-8",errors="strict")
            names = string.split(', ')
            return names

    names = todaysnames()
    for name in names:
        print name
```

Comment: sheet.cell().value returns what? unicode string? a byte string?

Comment: try urllib.unquote(string)   , import urllib for using it.

Comment: urllib.unquote didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed encoding to `iso8859_13(Baltic languages)` and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem may be caused by the `print`. The xlrd returns utf8. Depending of the encoding of your console, the `print` may have difficulties to print it correctly. I've noticed this sometimes on a french Windows (where encoding is cp1252)

The following question: [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/117092) explains how to print unicode char on the console on Windows. I didn't try myself but it looks good.

I hope it helps

Comment: Judging from the solution @Ever arrived at, I suspect your answer was on the right track. (But you could explain the problem a little-- the link is useless to the uninitiated.)

Comment: Ok I've tried to explained a bit more :) . I didn't have a lot of time and just wanted to point @Ever on a possible cause of the problem. But as usual, it worths taking the required time on the 1st time! ;-)